# Djnago rest framework how to allow only update user own content only

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I don't want to allow any user update another user object. I want to allow only update user own content. here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
    

    def update(self, request, slug=None):
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [object level permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#object-level-permissions). Create a custom permission class called `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the blog.
        return obj.author == request.user
```

Then, add this permission to `BlogViewSet`:

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
```

Comment: thanks it worked can we also add token base authentication. I mean users can update his own content using token? and where I can read more info about the `has_object_permission` function. is it custom builtin function? and will your function also prevent delete others user object ?

Comment: Great! You can read about `has_object_permission` in their documentation here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions . This should work for `DELETE` as well since it is not in `SAFE_METHODS`. It should also be independent of which authentication scheme you're using (token or basic auth).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [django-rest-framework-guardian](https://github.com/rpkilby/django-rest-framework-guardian) package. It is based on [django-quardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian). You should change your serializer like this:

```
from rest_framework_guardian.serializers import ObjectPermissionsAssignmentMixin
class BlogSerializer(ObjectPermissionsAssignmentMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
     model = Blog
     fields = "__all__"

  def get_permissions_map(self, created):
      current_user = self.context['request'].user
      readers = Group.objects.get(name='readers') # if you need
      supervisors = Group.objects.get(name='supervisors') # if you need

      return {
        'view_blog': [current_user, readers],
        'add_blod': [current_user],
        'change_blog': [current_user],
        'delete_blog': [current_user, supervisors]
      }
```

After that, you should add `ObjectPermissionsFilter` to `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings. It affect all views in your project:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": [
       "django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend",
       "rest_framework_guardian.filters.ObjectPermissionsFilter",
   ],
}
```

Those packages are suggested from Django Rest Framework check this [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions).